# Python:Pandas Find the availability of a text inside a Pandas (Dataframe)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am having two columns ColA ColB in pandas dataframe, 
I want to compare ColB with ColA if colA contains matching word with colB then i have to update colC as available.

```
If it not macthes print not available.
ColA                                                            ColB  
You can extract_insights on product reception                   insights
user various sources like extract_insights etc.                 insights   
some other sourced mail by using signals from state art         text
```

Note:Even if Column A contains any special characters still it should able to identify the colB text

Desired Output:

```
If it not macthes print not available.
ColA                                                           ColB     Colc
You can extract_insights on product reception                  insights AVB
user various sources like extract_insights etc.                insights AVB  
some other sourced mail by using signals from state art        text     NAVB
```

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001236/pythonpandas-find-the-availability-of-a-text-inside-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize example dataframe
data = [
    ["You can extract_insights on product reception", "insights"],
    ["user various sources like extract_insights etc.", "insights"],
    ["some other sourced mail by using signals from state art", "text"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["ColA", "ColB"])

# Create column C with comparison results
df["ColC"] = [
    "AVB" if (b in a) else "NAVB"
    for (a, b) in zip(df["ColA"], df["ColB"])
]

print(df)
# Output:
#                                                 ColA      ColB  ColC
# 0      You can extract_insights on product reception  insights   AVB
# 1    user various sources like extract_insights etc.  insights   AVB
# 2  some other sourced mail by using signals from ...      text  NAVB
```